# How can I buy tickets to see a performance in the Teatro Amazonas?

Tags: activities, brazil, entertainment

It seems the [Teatro Amazonas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Theatre) re-opened for performances in 2001.  But my searches so far have not lead me to tickets for performances--only tickets for guided tours.

According to Wikipedia, the Amazonas Philharmonic Orchestra regularly performs there, and the Festival Amazonas de Ópera is held there every spring, but there are also other performances.

If I want to see a performance in the Teatro Amazonas, where can I find a current schedule of performances, and hopefully book tickets online?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next to travel.se I am also a big fan of [Operabase](http://www.operabase.com). The userinterface might not be up to current standards, but they seem quite complete in their listings. as expected they do list the [Teatro Amazonica.](http://www.operabase.com/diary.cgi?lang=en&code=lbmaf&season=2012)

Tickets seems to be available through [online booking](http://www.operabase.com/mkhouse.cgi?lang=en&house=lbmaf), or purchase tickets to events [specifically at the Teatro Amazonas](http://www.bestseat.com.br/nfs/AMZ/Estabelecimento.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! By following your link, I was able to find exactly what I was looking for (and updated the question to include a specific link for Teatro Amazonas).

Answer (score 6):

I did some "googling" and the only thing I cam up with was this blog:

http://culturadoam.blogspot.com.br/ (Portuguese)

This is the cultural agenda of the Amazonas region, as it seems, where the theatre is included. It seems that the "Festival Amazonas de Ópera" is currently on the theater. I talked to a friend that was there very recently and she confirmed that they had the festival going. It's usually around April.

All the other "[official](http://www.culturamazonas.am.gov.br/programas_02.php?cod=0255)" pages ?? (Portuguese) from the theater have very scarce information. Nothing about tickets or the program.

This is their e-mail and local phone number:

teatroamazonas@culturamazonas.am.gov.br

Telefone: 
(92) 3622-1880 / 3622-2420

[image: Teatro Amazonas]

Comment: A strong lead... I might try my hand a crafting an email to them, with my very minimal Portugese.